Hooking up an Australian motor in USA
I have an Australian motor (240V single phase, Type I plug) that I want to use in USA. Australian 240V is 240V+Neutral+Earth(Ground). US 240V (NEMA 6 outlets) is 120V+120V+Earth. Can I simply rewire the motor cord to a NEMA 6 plug to connect the motor's hot+neutral to the two 120V lives, while keeping the earth as earth?
Other than the motor not running as fast (50Hz vs 60 Hz) is this sound, electrically speaking?

What does this motor power? Why not simply get one designed for US split phase 240v?

Should work. Except it will turn the wrong direction :-) https://www.flowwise.com.au/do-toilets-really-flush-backwards-in-australia/

Would probably be a good idea to ask your insurance company first.  Insurance companies hate paying out on claims and will work hard to find something.  An unlisted motor or a motor not installed to instructions will do it, if something happens.  The motor does not be need to be the cause, just it is there.

The bigger potential problem is that the motor (most likely, for common motor types) will run faster (not slower) than it's designed to run.

3600 rather than 3000 RPM
1800 rather than 1500 RPM
etc.

If it's not dual rated for 50/60Hz the overspeed can cause mechanical failure. It puts more force on the spinning rotor, and if that was not designed to spin faster it can fail.
Most 240V-only country equipment is designed to handle live/earth reversal without hazard (to accommodate the many countries that use non-polarized plugs) so the "neutral" motor lead going 120V from ground is not usually a problem as it's isolated from the grounded case just as the live lead  is.

With the reminder, as you state, that you definitely do want to connect shell to ground. As stated, in answer, most motors have windings isolated from shell,  but for safety, grounding is needed.

Intention to connect earth/ground was stated in question, unequivocally.
